# How To Save My Screenshot in java

Tags: java, file, screenshot, actionlistener, javax.imageio

I'm making a program that takes a screenshot and I want to have it so that i have a JButton with an actionlistener that when pressed it saves the image to a certain folder that if does not already exists it makes.

here is what I thought I should do:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    File dir = new File("C://SnippingTool+/" +  date.getDay());
    dir.mkdirs();
try {
    ImageIO.write(shot, "JPG", dir);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    }

});
```

I think it has something to do with my `File dir = new File` and that I am not saving to to the right place.

Here is my `Robot` taking a screenshot:

```
try {
shot = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
    } catch (HeadlessException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (AWTException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as I see it is with these two lines...

```
File dir = new File("C://SnippingTool+/" +  date.getDay());
dir.mkdirs();
```

This now means that the output you are trying to write to is a directory, when `ImageIO` is expecting a file, this will fail...

Instead try something like...

```
File output = new File("C://SnippingTool+/" +  date.getDay() + ".jpg");
File dir = output.getParentFile();
if (dir.exists() || dir.mkdirs()) {
    try {
        ImageIO.write(shot, "JPG", output);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }    
} else {
    System.out.println("Bad Path - " + dir);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, i tried that and for some reason i still got an error. Anything else i could do?

Comment: You not have permissions to write to C:\, trying using something like `System.getProperty("user.home")` as your base path instead

Comment: @MadProgrammer I did that, where does that save to?

Comment: @StephenC `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at main$2$2.actionPerformed(main.java:148)` That is at the `File output = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + date.getDay() + ".jpg");` (I changed the "C:\\" to System.getProperty("User.home")).

Comment: Sorry, try user.dir instead. This will translate to your user home directory, ie under windows 7, it will be /users/{username}

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment:

> ```
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException 
>     at main$2$2.actionPerformed(main.java:148)
> ```
>
> That is at the:
>
> ```
> File output = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + 
>                        date.getDay() + ".jpg");
> ```
>
> (I changed the "C:\" to System.getProperty("User.home")).

There are only two possible causes of an NPE in that line (wrapped for readability):

- If `System.getProperty` cannot find the named property, it will return a `null`.  Now the `"user.home"` property *should* exist ... but `"User.home"` almost certainly does NOT exist.  (Property names are case sensitive!!)
- If `date` is `null` or `date.getDay()` returns `null`.  We don't know how you initialized `date` ... or even what type it is.  (Though `Date` would be a good guess ...)

---

Both the `"user.home"` property and the `"user.dir"` property would work ... though they mean different things.