# Exception when I try to save a screenshot in Java

Tags: java, exception, selenium, screenshot

I am working with selenium and I wrote a method that takes screenshot and saves it in specified folder, but it keeps throwing an exception. Why?
Here is my code:

```
    public void takeScreenshot(WebDriver driver) throws IOException{
    Date date = new Date();
    String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy_HH:mm:ss").format(date).concat(".jpeg");
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    File destFile = new File(SCREENSHOTS.toString().concat(fileName));
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, destFile);
}
```

I am getting following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Screenshots\09-13-15_02:10:52.jpeg (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

Comment: maybe you can't use colon (`:`) in the file name?

Comment: Yesss!!! What was I thinking of?? of course I can not use semicolon!!!

Comment: Actually semicolon (`;`) you can use. I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the : to stop separate time, maybe that's an unacceptable character for a file name. Try with dots as the file system surely accepts well the dots

Answer (score 5):

Apparently you’re running windows, so:

[image: “A file name can’t contain any of the following characters: \ / : * ? " < > |”]

Answer (score 2):

I don't see you creating the destination file in the code you posted, the code below should do it.

```
File destFile = new File(SCREENSHOTS.toString().concat(fileName));
if (!destFile.exists()) {
     destFile.mkdir();
}
```

You can have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625976/how-to-save-my-screenshot-in-java) for more information.